# How to calculate percentage in Kotlin

Tags: android, math, kotlin

I need to calculate a percentage in Kotlin. I tried but failed to get the correct answer:

```
var percentage = (count/totalCount) * 100
it.toast("Percentage: $percentage")
```

What is the proper syntax in Kotlin?

Comment: If count and totalCount are integers then count/totalCount does integer division. Change to: `var percentage = 100.0 * count / totalCount`

Comment: val size = 10f
val percentage = percentTrip / totalTrip * 100f

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Most likely, you're struggling with the fact that applying the division operator on two integers will result in an integer division being performed, yielding an integer result.

The trick is to promote one of the operands to a floating point type:

```
var percentage = (count.toDouble() / totalCount) * 100
```

Comment: Great man but its return value in point but we need integer values in case of percentage?

Comment: Convert back toInt()

Comment: Hi @RobbyCornelissen: a) Changing type of one operand to `double` will have any unexpected result like `nan` error or is it totally safe to follow above steps ?
Please guide. (b) In my case, I have two operands both are of type `Long`, so shall I convert one to type `Int`

Comment: 1) I'm not aware of any integer value that will produce `NaN` when cast to a double. For this specific case, as long as you don't divide by 0, you should be fine. 2) You can directly convert the long to a double, although you will lose precision if your long is in the 2^52 to 2^63 range, either positive or negative.

Comment: @SVK Forgot to tag you. See comment above.

Answer (score 7):

This is an extension function to do it everywhere:

```
fun Int.divideToPercent(divideTo: Int): Int {
        return if (divideTo == 0) 0
        else (this / divideTo.toFloat() * 100).toInt()
}
```

and use it like this:

```
val pecent = 10.divideToPercent(20)
```

The `percent` will be 50.

You can even make it an infix fuction:

```
infix fun Int.percentOf(value: Int): Int {
        return if (this == 0) 0
        else (value / this.toFloat()).toInt()
}
```

and use it like this:

```
val pecent = 10 percentOf 200
```

The `percent` will be 20

Comment: You have a mistyped variable `pecent`. Shouldn't it be "percent"?

Answer (score 0):

If your min value is not `0`

```
private fun toPercent(rawValue: Int, min: Int, max: Int) : Double {
    val range = max - min
    val normalizedValue = rawValue - min
    return (normalizedValue.toDouble() / range) * 100
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val percentage = (count * 100) / totalCount
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.